# In SSRS custom code, can we create a function that call another function?

Tags: function, reporting-services

In the Custom code section, if I defined function 1 first, in the next line, can I define function 2 that calling function 1? If not, how can I get around it?

Comment: are you trying to say that you want to call it recursively ?

Comment: Try it and see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Artificially simple example:

```
Function SumSum(a as decimal, b as decimal) as decimal
Dim c as Decimal
c = a + b
Return c
End Function

Function OtherFunction(a as decimal, b as decimal) as decimal
Dim c as Decimal
c = SumSum(a,b)
Return c
End Function
```

OtherFunction will use the SumSum function to sum a and b.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It helps a lot.